# Равномерная выборка записей в Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Доброй ночи, господа.
Возникла необходимость решить проблему равномерности выборки данных из бд.
В качестве более понятного примера:
Нужно выбрать 120 записей с весом от 10 до 12 кг, при этом материал должен быть например пластик или металл.
И вроде бы просто должно быть нечто вроде:

```
select obj.*
from objects obj
where obj.weight >= 10 and obj.weight <= 12 and
(obj.material = 'пластик' or obj.material = 'металл' )
limit 120;
```

Но проблема в том что такой запрос вполне вероятно на большой базе выдаст мне 120 записей с весом 10 кг и материалом - металл, что в моей ситуации не подходит.

Нужна именно равномерная выборка: 20 пластиковых по 10 кг, 20 пластиковых по 11 кг, 20 пластиковых по 12 кг, 20 металлических по 10 кг и далее по аналогии. Итого в сумме как раз те 120 требуемых.

Были мысли циклом пройтись по всем условиям, построить запросы для каждой из вышеперечисленных частей и получить ещё ряд вытекающих проблем с производительностью и корректировкой выборки в случае недостатка в количестве записей по одной из групп условий.

Может быть я изобретаю велосипед и существует готовое решение моей проблемы или же более оптимальное направление решения? Работаю с PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чуть доработанный запрос **Мелкий**:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT ROW_NUMER()OVER(ORDER BY order_in_group)AS total_order, T.* 
  FROM (
    SELECT obj.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY material, weight) AS order_in_group,
    FROM objects obj
    WHERE obj.weight >= 10 and obj.weight <= 12 and
      (obj.material = 'пластик' or obj.material = 'металл' )
  )T
)T
WHERE total_order <= 120;
```

Для каждого уникального набора значений `material, weight` мы пронумеровали строки(`order_in_group`).
затем нумеруем с сортировкой по полученному номеру (`total_order`) - и берём первые 120 записей. Таким образом мы не зная сколько значений материалов и веса, выдадим от каждой группы значений поровну(или все, если значений в какой-то группе не хватает).

Т.е. решаем проблему:*недостатка в количестве записей по одной из групп условий.*

Если хочется каждый раз в результате запроса видеть различные данные. можно слегка изменить сортировку `order_in_group`: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY material, weight ORDER BY random())`

ps: вторая нумерация не обязательна, это я для наглядности + мне не нравится использовать нестандартный `limit`. Но можно написать чуть проще:

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM (
  SELECT obj.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY material, weight) AS order_in_group,
  FROM objects obj
  WHERE obj.weight >= 10 and obj.weight <= 12 and
    (obj.material = 'пластик' or obj.material = 'металл' )
)T
ORDER BY order_in_group
LIMIT 120;
```

Comment: Натыкался на безграничных просторах на подобное решение, но видимо что-то у меня тогда пошло не так. На этот раз немного подкорректировал запрос и получилось именно то что нужно. Спасибо за помощь!

P.S. Для разных данных там более усложненная логика и рандомом там не отделаешься. Необходимо выдавать данные не более одного раза в определенный промежуток времени, но это уже другая история.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT /**/ FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY material, weight ORDER BY /*по какому критерию отсортировать записи в группе и выбрать 10 из всех подходящих*/) AS lim,
    /**/
  from objects obj
  where obj.weight >= 10 and obj.weight <= 12 and
    (obj.material = 'пластик' or obj.material = 'металл' )
) x
WHERE x.lim <= 10;
```

Будут возвращены по 10 записей каждого имеющегося в таблице блока material и weight. Общий limit необязателен.

Comment: всё вроде хорошо, но по 10 строк из каждой группы?
Это не решает проблемы: _корректировкой выборки в случае недостатка в количестве записей по одной из групп условий._

Answer (score 3):

Такой костыль вас устроит?

```
select obj.*
from objects obj
where obj.weight >= 10 and obj.weight <= 12 and
(obj.material = 'пластик' or obj.material = 'металл' )
order by random()
limit 120;
```

Идея простая - превратить все записи таблицы в фарш рандомизацией.

Comment: Все равно нет гарантии что этот фарш будет равномерно распределённым